# How to instantiate multipe variables of multiple types from a method which returns a tuple in Scala

Tags: scala

I have a method which returns a tuple:

```
def someMethod(k: someType): (TypeA, TypeB) = ...
```

I want to call this method and retrieve the objects of TypeA and TypeB. What is the simplest way to do this?

This does not work:

```
val (a, b): TypeA, TypeB = myObj.someMethod(someInput)
```

what does?

Comment: Why not try and see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can (why don't you check it yourself?)

```
scala> def f(): (Int, Int) = (5, 6)
f: ()(Int, Int)
scala> val (a, b) = f()
a: Int = 5
b: Int = 6
```

Note, however, that you cannot do multiple assignment to existing variables. Google it, the question has been asked many times.

By the way, your specification of Tuple's type is wrong, you have to wrap it in braces if you want to indicate the type explicitly:

```
scala> val (c, d): Int, String  = (3, "hi")
<console>:1: error: pattern definition may not be abstract
       val (c, d): Int, String  = (3, "hi")
           ^

scala> val (c, d): (Int, String)  = (3, "hi")
c: Int = 3
d: String = hi
```

Comment: The reason i'm asking (i've searched google) is because I did not find an answer where the type of the returned objects is specified. Thanks